# Insert a data after updating it

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I get the values from the table `product` after updating the data and insert it in the table `purchases`. My code does work in the `UPDATE` but does not in the insert part `purchases`.

```
<?php

$ID=$_GET["stocksid"];
$res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=$ID");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $product_name=$row["product_name"];
    $product_price=$row["product_price"];
    $selling_price=$row["selling_price"];
    $product_img=$row["product_image"];
    $product_qty=$row["product_qty"];
    $product_category=$row["product_category"];
    $product_discount=$row["discount"];
    $product_desc=$row["p_desc"];
}
?>

        <form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td name="prod_name"><?php echo $product_name ?></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Image</td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $product_img; ?>" height="100" width="100" name="prod_img"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pprice" value="<?php echo $product_price?>" disabled> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Selling Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sprice" value="<?php echo $selling_price ?>"disabled></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Quantity(Current: <?php echo $product_qty?> )</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pqty"required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Category</td>
            <td name="prod_cat">
<?php echo $product_category ?>
          </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Discount </td>
            <td name="prod_disc">  <?php echo $product_discount ?>% </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td name="prod_desc">
<?php echo $product_desc?>"
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Add Stocks"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST["submit1"])) {
        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

        $product_qty =  $_POST["pqty"] + $product_qty;

        mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE product 
                            SET product_qty='$product_qty' 
                            WHERE id=$ID ");

        $res1=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from product where id=$ID");
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
            $ID=$row1["id"];
            $prod_name = $row1["product_name"];
            $prod_price = $row1["product_price"];
            $prod_img = $row1["product_image"];
            $prod_cat = $row1["product_category"];
            $prod_desc = $row1["p_desc"];
        }
        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $totalcost = $_POST["pqty"]*$product_price;

        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT into purchases 
                        values('','$ID','$prod_name','$prod_desc',
                            '$prod_price','$prod_cat','$_POST[pqty]',
                            '$prod_img','$totalcost','$dataTime')");

?>
```

Comment: Have you debugged it and made sure that it does not give an error when running it and verified that there is data in your variables?

Comment: Because you haven't return what's inserted in to database.

Comment: I assume a query using `WHERE id=$ID` will return only one row? If so WHY are you using a WHILE Loop to fetch ONE ROW. It makes the code unintuitive and difficult to understand and wastes the resources required to setup and run an unnecessary while loop

Comment: When you POST the form you will not have anything in `$_GET["stocksid"];`

Comment: Therefore when you try and run the Update and following select you have NO KEY to use in the WHERE clause

Comment: Just solved my problem, thanks for your help guys! appriciated it! I just used the Error checking and generate some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written any code for fetching data after it's been inserted into database.

use [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) function to get id of last inserted record. And then fetch it using `Select * from...` same way that you have done after update query.